# How to connect XP mode VM to the host so as to simulate LAN Activities?

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-virtual-pc, windows-xp-mode

First of all my PC config:

Host:**Windows 7(32-bit)**

Guest: **Windows XP SP3 as XP Mode.**

Integration Features Disabled(I don't think it has any thing to do with networking).

Network Connections on Host :

1.Local Area Connection(Realtek...) - **unplugged**(as no other PC is connected).

2.Nokia 2730 classic USB Modem - I use this connect to the internet.

Now,How can I connect the guest to the host as if they were on a LAN.
Please give specific steps as I am using Windows XP Mode/Virtual machine for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

To establish a Guest to Host connection, follow the steps in [this blog post](http://blog.hmobius.com/post/2009/12/24/How-to-get-Windows-7-XP-Mode-Apps-to-talk-to-SQL-2008-on-your-Windows-7-Host-OS.aspx#comment):

> In brief
>
> - Install the Loopback Network Adapter on your Windows 7 machine
> - Set the
>     Loopback Adapter to have a static IP address which the VPC network
>     adapter will use as its internet gateway
> - Configure the XP Mode Virtual
>     Machine to use the loopback adapter as its gateway.
> - You should now be
>     able to ping your host machine from your guest OS.
> - Open SQL Server connections via TCP/IP on host machine [updated 24/12]
> - Open incoming
>     connections on port 1433/1434 for windows firewall
> - You should now be able to telnet to port 1433 on the host OS from XP mode

If those steps do not work for you, then try using different IP addresses (I used `10.0.0.199` (Host), `10.0.0.200` (Guest), and of course `255.255.255.0` (subnet mask).  You can confirm by pinging the Host IP (`10.0.0.199`) from within XP Mode.  Make sure on Windows 7 you create Windows Firewall exceptions for the ports you need.

In addition to those steps, you may also add a second network adapter to your XP Mode through the Virtual PC settings, selecting the network adapter on your host that has the internet connection.  In the XP Mode IPv4 properties for the second network adapter, use all automatic settings.

You will now have a network path to your Windows 7 host and internet access.

Answer (score 1):

In the VM network setup, you need to make sure the connection is setup as a `Bridge`. This will allow the VM's network connection to go through the hosts connection and act as if it is on the network.

Comment: With Virtual PC (What XP Mode is running on top of) it does not use the term `Bridged` it actually lists the network adapter's name

Comment: Is the loopback supposed to show up as an option when I'm configuring the guests' network?

Also, if I give the loopback a static ip address on the host, is there anything special I should use for its default gateway?

Lastly, if the guest (WXP) has a VPN, will I be able to get to it from the host?